# Finding the rhyming words in a corpus with R, regex

Tags: r, regex, corpus, linguistics, false-positive

I have the following corpus:

```
corpus_rhyme <- c("helter-skelter", "lovey-dovey", "riff-raff", "hunter-gatherer", 
                  "day-to-day", "second-hand", "chock-a-block")
```

Out of all of these words I only need words like  "helter-skelter", "lovey-dovey" and "chock-a-block", which are rhyming reduplicatives with a change of consonants. They are usually spelled with a hyphen, and may have a medial component in between the elements, such as "a" in "chock-a-block". I only need to find rhyming reduplicative expressions that have the same number of syllables. For example, although "phoney-baloney" is a rhyming reduplicative, I do not need it.

I was using the following code to find rhyming reduplicatives:

```
rhyme<- grep("\\b(\\w*)(\\w{2,}?)-(\\w{1,}?-)?\\w*\\2\\b", corpus_rhyme,
             ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

This code produces too many false positives. The output is as follows:

```
rhyme
[1] "helter-skelter"  "lovey-dovey"     "riff-raff"       "hunter-gatherer" "day-to-day"      "second-hand"    
[7] "chock-a-block"
```

I was sifting out these false positives manually, which takes too much time. Can anyone advise a better version of this line of code to reduce the number of false positives? For example, "riff-raff" comes up because I want at least 2 last letters to be the same at the end of a reduplicative expression, otherwise I will miss expressions like "rat-tat". But can we specify in this code that these two letters have to be different from each other, so that "rat-tat" is found ("a" is different from "t"), but "riff-raff" ("f" and "f" are the same) does not come up?
Another possible improvement: how can I get rid of words like "day-to-day" where the two elements are exactly the same? I only need rhyming reduplicatives that have a difference in the initial consonants.
Finally, I am not sure if anything can be done about "hunter-gatherer", unless there is a way to calculate the number of syllables and make sure that both elements of the expression have the same number of syllables.

Comment: Given that you're looking for rhymes, might it be useful to use a pronunciation dictionary as well? https://github.com/trevorld/r-cmudict includes several for different varieties of English. It wouldn't help with all the corpus terms, but it might help to remove false positives that are words in the pronouncing dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution, there is most probably an easier way:

```
# Count the number of hyphens in each element: hyphen_count => integer vector
hyphen_count <- lengths(regmatches(corpus_rhyme, gregexpr("\\-", corpus_rhyme)))

# Check if the expression rhymes: named logical vector => stdout(console)
vapply(ifelse(hyphen_count == 1, 
      gsub('^[^aeiouAEIOU]+([aeiou]+\\w+)\\s*\\-[^aeiouAEIOU]+([aeiou]+\\w+)', '\\1 \\2', corpus_rhyme),
      gsub('^[^aeiouAEIOU]+([aeiou]+\\w+)\\s*\\-\\w+\\-[^aeiouAEIOU]+([aeiou]+\\w+)', '\\1 \\2', corpus_rhyme)
), function(x){
    split_string <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s"))
    identical(split_string[1], split_string[2])
  }, logical(1)
)
```

Data:

```
corpus_rhyme <- c("helter-skelter", "lovey-dovey", "riff-raff", "hunter-gatherer", 
                  "day-to-day", "second-hand", "chock-a-block")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is general phenomenon that last three letters or more of the first word are the same as last three letters or more of the last word, then you could try this:

```
grep(".*(\\w{3,})-([aeiou]-)?(\\w+)(\\1)", corpus_rhyme,ignore.case = TRUE,value=TRUE)

#[1] "helter-skelter" "lovey-dovey"    "chock-a-block"
```